# Error : The OutputPath property is not set for project 'Project.Web.csproj'

Tags: visual-studio-2012, jenkins, msbuild

Building my Jenkins/MSBuild solution gives me this error

Build started 18-03-2017 14:38:15.
Project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Development\Project.Web\Project.Web.csproj" on node 1 (default targets).
  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(609,5): 
error : The OutputPath property is not set for project 'Project.Web.csproj'.  Please check to make sure that
 you have specified a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this project.
Configuration='Release'  Platform='BPC'.  You may be seeing this message because you are trying to 
build a project without a solution file, and have specified a non-default Configuration or Platform 
that doesn't exist for this project. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Development\Project.Web\Project.Web.csproj]
Done Building Project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Development\Project.Web\Project.Web.csproj" 
(default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Development\Project.Web\Project.Web.csproj" (default target) 
(1) ->(_CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform target) -> 
  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(609,5): 
error : The OutputPath property is not set for project 'Project.Web.csproj'.  Please check to make sure that
 you have specified a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this project.
Configuration='Release'  Platform='BPC'.  You may be seeing this message because you are trying to 
build a project without a solution file, and have specified a non-default Configuration or Platform 
that doesn't exist for this project. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Development\Project.Web\Project.Web.csproj]

```
0 Warning(s)
1 Error(s)
```

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.61
Build step 'Build a Visual Studio project or solution using MSBuild' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

I have this in my .csproj file

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">Any CPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>
    </ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{F1258E67-9E32-480033D0}</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-165b846f21};{fae04ef79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>Project.Web</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Project.Web</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <MvcBuildViews>false</MvcBuildViews>
    <UseIISExpress>true</UseIISExpress>
    <IISExpressSSLPort />
    <IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication />
    <IISExpressWindowsAuthentication />
    <IISExpressUseClassicPipelineMode />
    <WebGreaseLibPath>..\packages\WebGrease.1.5.2\lib</WebGreaseLibPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release-VersionIncrement|Any CPU' ">
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <CodeAnalysisUseTypeNameInSuppression>true</CodeAnalysisUseTypeNameInSuppression>
    <CodeAnalysisModuleSuppressionsFile>GlobalSuppressions.cs</CodeAnalysisModuleSuppressionsFile>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|Any CPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|Any CPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you try to build solution which have incorrect project' platform and configuration for current solution's platform and configuration. How you can see platform `BPC` is not defined in your project. Check `.sln` file or build only `.csproj` file with `MSBuild`.